# Vim command 'ciw' does not work

Tags: vim

I'm using version 7.1.138 on Ubuntu 8.04, on this machine ciw - change inner word command does not work. No custom settings is done to vim. Does someone know why?

Comment: FWIW: :ver will tell you the features compiled into vim. It may be that textobjects is turned off in your build.

Answer (score 7):

Open Vim and enter

```
:version
```

to see if textobject has been enabled at compile time in your version of Vim.

Comment: Yes, there we have it. Features included (+) or not (-): -textobjects.

Comment: The next question is, how does i enable textobjects?

Comment: @jnstq, Sorry mate. That's a compile time options afaik.

Comment: Don't (never?) use a lite-version of vim. On some distributions, starting vi instead of vim will start vim is a degraded lite-mode.

Comment: @Luc, superbe! I was wondering about why I was getting the reduced vi by default. +1

Answer (score 3):

Debian/Ubuntu install vim-tiny by default. Installing the vim package gives you the full version. There's also vim-gnome (previously vim-full) which includes the full version as well as a GUI version. As far as I know (and there's nothing about this in the man page), vim behaves the same regardless of whether you invoke it as vi.